# Is that possible to discover user input wifi credential is valid or not without connection?

Tags: android, node.js, networking, wifi

If the user input wifi credential, eg.

`{ ssid: "home-wifi", psk: "home1234" }`

(assuming home-wifi is near)

Is there a way to know wifi credential is valid or not without connection?

simply, is there a way like below?

```
isValidCredential('home-wifi', 'home1234', function(isValid){

    // this will print true or false       
    console.log(isValid);

})
```

Comment: no, the only way to check it is to try to connect.

Comment: @VladMatvienko How about try to connect, get `success` or `fail`, and then back to the previous network? It look possible?

Comment: yes, this could be a solution, if you are able to connect back to current network. I'm not sure is you can do without knowing the password of current network. To check result of connection, see off docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#addNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration) it returns -1 in case of fail, and other value in case of success.